# Sudoku Game in Python

Tags: python, sudoku

I need help with my code. I know how to start the board, but I don't know how to check if the numbers repeat in rows and columns, and how to change it.

Lists, matrices, for loops

```py
import turtle
import random
import time

board = [                        #Initialize board.
            ["X","X","X","X"],
            ["X","X","X","X"],
            ["X","X","X","X"],
            ["X","X","X","X"]
            ]

values = ["0","1","2","3"]      #Accepted values

def sudoku():
    #Start screen
    print("SUDOKU".center(50,"-"))
    print("Rules")                #To be changed later c:
    start = int(input("Type 1 to start."))
    crearTablero()
    checkDuplicates()

def createBoard():
    for row in range(len(board)):
        if row%2 == 0:
            board[row][0] = random.sample(values,1)
            board[row][2] = random.sample(values,1)

        if row%2 == 1:
            board[row][1] = random.sample(values,1)
            board[row][3] = random.sample(values,1)

        print(board[row])

def checkDuplicates():                  #Check for duplicates while creating 
    for column in range(len(board[0])):
        #Tried to check if a number has been used in the column, change it to a new number
        val = [x for x in val]          
        for i in range(4):
            while board[columna][0] != board[columna][i]:
                celda = board[columna][i]
                celda = random.sample(valores,1)
                celdastr = "".join(celda)
                check = val.index(celdastr) #I'm stuck here. I get ValueError when trying to delete the used number from val.
                if check != "-1":
                    val.remove(check)

#I still have to create functions to enter the answer, check it and check if the board is full

sudoku()
```

I get a ValueError when trying to remove from value list, and the numbers don't change :(.

> > Traceback (most recent call last):   File "sudoku.py", line 54, in 
> >         sudoku()   File "sudoku.py", line 21, in sudoku
> >         checarDuplicado()   File "sudoku.py", line 52, in checarDuplicado
> >         val.remove(check) ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Comment: please post the full traceback of the ValueError you are getting.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.  Your code does not produce the error you claim.

Comment: [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  You didn't post the expected output; you didn't make any debugging attempt; your code fails for undefined symbols.

Answer (score 0):

If you reduced your example to a minimal form you would find it is this:

```
val = ["a"]
celdastr = "b"
check = val.index(celdastr)
if check != "-1":
    val.remove(celdastr)
```

and that the root cause of your problem is `check != "-1"`.

The `list.index(item)` function returns integer indexes, not strings - you need to have `check != -1` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
SIZE = 9
SUB_SIZE = 3
sudoku = [9*[0]]
p = 1
while p != 9:
    sudoku.append (9*[0])
    p += 1

def printSudoku():
    for x in sudoku:
        print("-------------------------------------")
        for y in x:
            print("|", y,end = " ")
        print("| ")
    print("-------------------------------------")

row = int(input("Enter the row \n"))
while row > 8 or row < 0:
    row = int(input("Enter a valid row number(between 0-8) \n"))

col = int(input("Enter the column \n"))
while col > 8 or col < 0:
    col = int(input("Enter a valid column number(between 0-8) \n"))

val = int(input("Enter the value \n"))
while val > 9 or val < 1:
    val = int(input("Enter a valid value(between 1-9) \n"))

sudoku[row][col] = val

while row != -1:
    row = int(input("Enter the row \n"))
    while row > 8 or row < -1:
        row = int(input("Enter a valid row number(between 0-8) \n"))
    col = int(input("Enter the column \n"))
    while col > 8 or col < 0:
        col = int(input("Enter a valid column number(between 0-8) \n"))   
    val = int(input("Enter the value \n"))
    while val > 9 or val < 0:
        val = int(input("Enter a valid value(between 1-9) \n"))

    sudoku[row][col] = val

printSudoku()

def isAvailable(row, col, num):

    rowStart = int(int(row/3) * 3);
    colStart = int(int(col/3) * 3);
    i = 0
    while(i<9):
        if (sudoku[row][i] == num):
            return False
        if (sudoku[i][col] == num):
            return False
        if (sudoku[int(rowStart + (i%3))][int(colStart + (i/3))] == num):
            return False

        i = i+1
    return True;

def fillSudoku(row, col):

    if(row<9 and col<9):

        if(sudoku[row][col] != 0):

            if((col+1)<9):
                return fillSudoku(row, col+1)
            elif((row+1)<9):
                return fillSudoku(row+1, 0)
            else:
                return True
        else:
            i = 0
            while(i<9):
                if(isAvailable(row, col, i+1)):
                    sudoku[row][col] = i+1
                    if((col+1)<9):
                        if(fillSudoku(row, col +1)):
                            return True
                        else :
                            sudoku[row][col] = 0
                    elif((row+1)<9):
                        if(fillSudoku(row+1, 0)):
                            return True;
                        else:
                            sudoku[row][col] = 0
                    else :
                        return True;
                i = i+1
        return False;
    else:
        return True;

if (fillSudoku(0, 0)) : 
    print ("\n\nSolution is \n")
    printSudoku()

else :
    print("\n\nNO SOLUTION\n\n")
```

Enter row as -1 when you're finished entering the values

The row and column number start from 0 instead of 1

Answer (score 0):

This function checks whether a list passed as an argument contains nine digits from '1' to '9'

```
def checkset(digs):
    return sorted(list(digs)) == [chr(x + ord('0')) for x in range(1, 10)]
```

This will be a list of rows representing the sudoku

```
rows = [ ]
for r in range(9):
    ok = False
    while not ok:
        row = input("Enter row #" + str(r + 1) + ": ")
        ok = len(row) == 9 or row.isdigit()
        if not ok:
            print("Incorrect row data - 9 digits required")
    rows.append(row)

ok = True
```

Check if all rows are good

```
for r in range(9):
    if not checkset(rows[r]):
        ok = False
        break
```

Check if all columns are good

```
if ok:
    for c in range(9):
        col = []
        for r in range(9):
            col.append(rows[r][c])
        if not checkset(col):
            ok = False
            break
```

Check if all sub-squares (3x3) are good

```
if ok:
    for r in range(0, 9, 3):
        for c in range(0, 9, 3):
            sqr = ''
            # make a string containing all digits from a sub-square
            for i in range(3):
                sqr += rows[r+i][c:c+3]
            if not checkset(list(sqr)):
                ok = False
                break
```

Print the final verdict

```
if ok:
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

Comment: The line setting `ok=True` manually in the second code block seems strange. Doesn't one reach that line if and only if `ok==True` already?